# my webpage gets rendered multiple times when i submit once with post method to python flask

Tags: python, html, flask

```
@app.response("/process" , methods=['POST'])
def process():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

1. please find the solution for my issue here am using python flask and html

Comment: It needs more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From what you have given, this is the only solution I can think of. If this is not what you were looking for feel free to ask questions, thanks!

```
from Flask import request

@app.response("/process" , methods=['POST'])
def process():
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        <enter code here>
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')
```